# URL rewriting in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

I want to access a article with User friendly URL http://localhost/Content/Article/{id}/{title}, which internally process this url like http://localhost/Content/Article/{i}.  I have created an Url routing rule for these url which is

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Article",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "content", action = "article", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

However it is processing the request but, html respons is messing up.  It is changing all image, anchor, css, javascript url. Replacing root url with /Content/Article and my html is being displayed messed up.  All css formating gone.  I have tried IIS7.0 rewriting module and Asp.nET routing, both giving me this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all references to external files are relative to the root of your website.

This isn't an issue with ASP.NET routing, it's an issue with how you're referencing your external files.

Comment: Urls are relative,  I am using @Url.Content("~/Content/Images/img.png") as image source in View.  I am using Razor view.

Comment: when using url http://localhost/Content/Article/10/title it brings the correct page however it modify Img, Css url in response html.  I have Image folder in root, image should be "/Images/img.png" but response returning "/Conten/Images/img.png".  Similarly it is happening with css and scripts.

Comment: I have Content as physical folder where css and images are placed and also have ContentController in my site.  Can this be root cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly type the correct url into your browser do you get the correct page?

I have come across that problem a lot, especially when I have Areas.  I have found that using T4MVC (NuGet Package) for all @Html.ActionLinks, etc, solves the problem. For example, using T4MVC, instead of:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home Page", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

...you can write:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home Page", MVC.Home.Index())</li>
```

Note the MVC.Home.Index().  This is how T4MVC allows you to do away with the magic strings (actionName and controllerName).  In other words, T4MVC allows you to use the following overload of HtmlHelper.ActionLink:

```
HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, ActionResult result)
```

Instead of:

```
HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
```

For reasons that escape me right now (I have forgotten why!), this gets round the issue I think you are having.

Just check and see if typing the desired Url into the address bar works.  If so, then it is the links that are going bad, not the routing.

If you still have a problem, then this isn't the answer...